# Display Bitmap in Image Control

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I need to display Bitmap image from controller in HTML tag `<img />`. How can I do it?

**Please read**: this question is not "too broad". It specifically asks how to show `Bitmap` C# object in HTML image tag using ASP.NET MVC. Please reopen it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply use something like following

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Model.imageBytes))" />
```

Comment: If you start out with a .net Bitmap object, you'll need this intermediate step to go from Bitmap to an array of bytes: Model.imageBytes = (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(qrCodeBitMap, typeof(byte[]));

Answer (score 11):

You need to have a controller action which returns a FileStreamResult and then use an `<img />` tag pointing to this action.

### Action

```
public ActionResult Image()
{
    var bitmap = GetBitmap(); // The method that returns Bitmap
    var bitmapBytes = BitmapToBytes(bitmap); //Convert bitmap into a byte array
    return File(bitmapBytes, "image/jpeg"); //Return as file result
}

// This method is for converting bitmap into a byte array
private static byte[] BitmapToBytes(Bitmap img)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

### View

```
<img src='@Url.Action("image")' alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget to dispose the bitmap object.